# ARP reply to a request which asks MAC address from another broadcast domain

Tags: arp

I have a following network topology:

[image: ARP and SNAT]

Sometimes I see ARP requests from `server` which request MAC address for IPv4 address which is not in the broadcast domain:

```
18:37:01.707771 00:16:3e:1a:61:b5 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.251 tell 10.10.10.15, length 28
18:37:01.708165 00:16:3e:62:9f:51 > 00:16:3e:1a:61:b5, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.251 is-at 00:16:3e:62:9f:51, length 46
```

Why do hosts(`192.168.0.251` in example above) reply to such ARP requests? I would expect them to simply ignore such requests.

Comment: You have a network segment with two netblocks, the MAC in the ARP request matches the interface ...Is this a linux question?

Comment: Apparently MAC `00:16:3e:62:9f:51` thinks it is assigned this address, and it even answers. Which interface does this MAC belong to? Which interface does `00:16:3e:1a:61:b5` belong to?